# MySQL label statement not recognized in PROCEDURE declaration

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use a label statement in the MySQL exactly as described in doc.

I permanently get an error on the colon behind label :
What is wrong?
I already tried XAMPP with the MariaDB as well as WAMP with the MySQL. I try as simple procedure as possible. From SQL tab in phpMyAdmin as well as from file script in Import. All the same : Unexpected character near ":".

I found issue that the TAB in the procedure definition may cause problem. I have not there any TAB. I tried loop and LOOP, begin vs. BEGIN.... still same... Please help.

[image: screenshot in phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Did you try to create and run this stored proc with a different client, no with phpmyadmin? Just in case phpmyadmin is the buggy app...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tested also command line mysql.exe. Same result. I also changed label's and variable's names etc. No matter.

Answer (score 0):

You have `END LOOP` try changing it to `END LOOP loop1;` [see MySQL document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-labels.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confirmed to work fine in MySQL 5.6 -- here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c00911/1. I also suspect the phpMyAdmin client.

Try putting the label on its own line, or taking the numeric out of the label (take the word loop out of it, too -- maybe it's parsing it funny). Call it `var_counter` maybe.